# How to select a row where from and to date are exist in SQL DB

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, select

Hello i have a SQL Table which look like this:

```
RESERVATIONROOM:

ID          NAME            FROMDATE                       TODATE      

5           Room1        2012-11-29 11:46:00.000           2012-11-29 12:45:00.000
6           Room1        2012-11-29 12:55:00.000           2012-11-29 14:20:00.000
7           Room1        2012-11-29 15:00:00.000           2012-11-29 16:42:00.000
```

I have a from and a to date and i want to select all rooms which are between those two dates.

Example:

> form date: 2012-11-29 11:50:00.000
>   to date:   2012-11-29 13:46:00.000

The output should be like this:

> RESERVATIONROOM:
>
> ```
> ID          NAME            FROMDATE                       TODATE      
>
> 5           Room1        2012-11-29 11:46:00.000           2012-11-29 12:45:00.000
> 6           Room1        2012-11-29 12:55:00.000           2012-11-29 14:20:00.000
> ```

This is what i have so far:

```
SELECT* 
FROM RESERVATIONROOM
WHERE FROMDATE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'2012-11-29 11:50:00.000',101) AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'2012-11-29 13:46:00.000',101)
AND TODATE < CONVERT(DATETIME,'2012-11-29 13:46:00.000',101)
ORDER BY FROMDATE ASC
```

My Select Statement filters to much and i cant see all the dates which are between those two dates.

Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what are the types of these date columns, Datetime?

Comment: What is `BESETZT_BIS`, you haven't showed it.

Comment: yes they are datetime, sorry besetzt_bis is TODATE.

Comment: Why are you using varchars for datetimes at all? Use sql-parameters to avoid sql-injection and conversion issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for convert comment, i thought it was datetime to varchar convert.
But from your input date, you gave two date and table has two date for each room. It is actually confusing what are these from dates and to dates. From your example output, you should use `or` between two filter. Look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/867e9/8).
Good luck.

```
select * from table1
where (convert(datetime, @from, 101) between fromdate and todate)
or (convert(datetime, @to, 101) between fromdate and todate)
```

Comment: i must convert because ill get an error: convert varchar to datetime is out of range value...

Comment: it works on the website but not in my sql statement. i think there is a problme with the datetime convertion. it says sometimes that there is a out of range error while converting varchar to datetime

Comment: what is your dateformat? probably `dmy`. please add `set dateformat mdy` before your select query.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using varchars for datetimes at all? Use sql-parameters to avoid sql-injection and conversion issues.

Assuming that the parameters are already `datetimes`.

You can use `BETWEEN` on both columns for both parameters:

```
SELECT *
FROM RESERVATIONROOM
WHERE @dateFrom BETWEEN FROMDATE AND TODATE
 OR   @dateTO   BETWEEN FROMDATE AND TODATE
```

(i'm not sure if you need `AND` or `OR` in the `Where`-clause, do you want to include intersections?)

Comment: i think that there is a problem with the convertion of my datetime. the date is filtering but not the time. the real parameters are datetime but i want to try it out in ms sql before i add the statement in my code.

Comment: there is a problem with convertion style = 101. what else can i use?

Comment: @ErayGeveci: You can use `GetDate()` for the current time and [`DATADD(day,10,GetDate())`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) to get a different datetime for your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`WHERE FROMDATE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'2012-11-29 11:50:00.000',101) AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'2012-11-29 13:46:00.000',101)`

use

`WHERE FROMDATE > CONVERT(DATETIME,'2012-11-29 11:50:00.000',101)`